# JavaFX scene builder won't run

Tags: interface-builder, javafx

I'm a beginner in Java, so I'm looking for a help. I've installed Java 7u4, Java JDK 7u4, JavaFX 2.1.0 with SDK and JavaFX Scene Builder 1.0. All for Windows x32.
When I'm starting JavaFX Scene Builder dialog window showed this:

http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/1420/javafx.png
[image: error: could not create the java virtual machine. error: a fatal exception has occurred. program will exit. OK X]

Can you help me figure out how to run it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you create and run a HelloWorld application [in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html) and [in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you would try to reinstall it? I have installed it once and it worked perfectly. It's not very ok when you try to integrate it in fxml with a controller.

Edit: If you're having a x64 OS installed i recommend to unistall and reinstall the x64 version!

Answer (score 0):

Reason: Deamon Tools Lite has conflicted with my installed JavaFX Scene Builder 1.0. I turned off this and problem has resolved